# Keras model won't use predict correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Keras model that I have trained and evaluated and even tested. Now I am trying to use three test images into the model.

I run the images through a preprocessor which is the same one I used to make the training data. I then do the exact same thing to the single images that I did for the testing data. But it gives me an error of

> Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays:

I don't know what is wrong with it.

So this is how I test the model successfully.

```
y_pred = []
y_true = []
for i in range(0, len(test_x1)):
    x1 = test_x1[i]
    x2 = test_x2[i]
    x1 = np.expand_dims(x1, axis=0)
    x2 = np.expand_dims(x2, axis=0)
    y_true.append(np.argmax(test_y[i]))
    pred = model.predict([x1, x2])
    y_pred.append(make_binary(pred))
```

This is the preprocessing method I used for both images

```
def create_features(file, image_dir, base_model):
    img_path = os.path.join(image_dir, file)
    img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    img = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = resnet50.preprocess_input(img)
    x = np.array([x])
    feature = base_model.predict(x)
    return feature
```

And this is the way I am processing the new images:

```
IMAGE_DIR = 'Data'
img1 = 'test1.jpg'
img2 = 'test2.jpg'
img3 = 'test3.jpg'

img1_feat = create_features(img1, IMAGE_DIR, model)
img2_feat = create_features(img2, IMAGE_DIR, model)
img3_feat = create_features(img3, IMAGE_DIR, model)
```

Now when I look at the two features they are the same.

```
x1 = test_x1[0]
x1 = np.expand_dims(x1, axis=0)
print(x1.shape)
print(type(x1))

print(img1_feat.shape)
print(type(img1_feat))
(1, 1, 1000)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1, 1, 1000)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And then I try to make a prediction from it

```
pred1 = model.predict([img1_feat, img2_feat])
```

But that results in an error.

Comment: Does your model take two inputs?

Comment: Yes like this [x1, x2]

Comment: No, I mean that there are two Input layers, because the model you are using seems to have one input, and you are giving two, that is the problem. Can you maybe include the model architecture code?

Comment: can you post output of model.summary()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong thanks to @Matias Valdenegro and @Mukul
I was doing this in an Ipython notebook and after a few epochs go around I found out that on occasion the model gets overwritten by an imported resent model from another class. 
Thanks to everyone for the help. I didnt think about using the model.summary() as I didnt really think that it has changed.